# How MyBatis intergrated into Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Every sincere one on the net, I am brand new to this site eager for your help! Yesterday, I've just integrated MyBatis into Spring Boot by configuring bean via Annotation style.

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBatisBuild {

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory createSqlSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        SqlSessionFactoryBuilder sqlSessionFactoryBuilder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("MyBatis.config.xml");
        return sqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Relative Controller:

```
@RestController
public class DiaryController {

    private DiaryService diaryService;

    @GetMapping("/diary/all")
    public List<Diary> getAll() {
        return diaryService.getAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDiaryService(DiaryService diaryService) {
        this.diaryService = diaryService;
    }
}
```

The Service injected:

```
@Service
public class DiaryService {

    private final SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public DiaryService(@Autowired SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        this.sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    public List<Diary> getAll() {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, TransactionIsolationLevel.READ_UNCOMMITTED);
        List<Diary> list = sqlSession.selectList("com.qlintonger.xxlint.dao.DiaryDao.getAllDiaries");
        sqlSession.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

The request flow concurrency test result:

[My-Own Concurrency Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoKY5.png)

For comparison, place officially MyBatis-Spring integration concurrency result convincing that every Model, Mapper, Service and Controller settings are all the same:

[MyBatis-Spring Concurrency Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja84a.png)

As you can see, there exists barely 600+ concurrency requests differs in between. I would like to ask whether my implementation is not accurate? Is this about me not hooking into Spring Beans life cycle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that share code as images instead of code blocks usually indicate you haven't read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and people often skip right over them. So share your code as indicated. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

why not use *mybatis-spring-boot-starter*

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```